# Voice Channel Audit-log

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
      let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
      let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


      if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
      send_log(
        c,
        newMember.guild,
        "RED",
        "Voice Channel",
        `${newMember.user} has joined ${newUserChannel}`

      )
     } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
      send_log(
        c,
        newMember.guild,
        "RED",
        "Voice Channel",
        `${newMember.user} has left'd ${oldUserChannel}`
      )
    // User leaves a voice channel

  }
})
```

Not bringing any errors up. But after user leaves or joins any VC, it says this.
`${newMember.user}` is bring up `undefined` and the `${oldUserChannel}` is also bringing up undefined.

Comment: waiting for comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short code that could help you

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldM, newM) => {
    if(!oldM.channel && newM.channel) {
        send_log(
        c,
        newM.guild,
        "RED",
        "Voice Channel",
        `${newM.member.user} joined ${newM.channel.name}`
         )
    } else if(oldM.channel && newM.channel && oldM.channel?.id !== newM.channel?.id) {
        send_log(
        c,
        newM.member.guild,
        "RED",
        "Voice Channel",
        `${newM.member.user} switched from ${oldM.channel.name} to ${newM.channel.name}`
         )
    } else if(oldM.channel && !newM.channel) {
        send_log(
        c,
        newM.guild,
        "RED",
        "Voice Channel",
        `${newM.member.user} left ${oldM.channel.name}`
         )
    }
})
```

I do not know what `c` is so you might have to define that somewhere.

Comment: Anyone... please help me with indentation, I am on mobile and I am still learning (if it's good, which I doubt, just tell me)

Comment: It looks ok, [here](https://i.imgur.com/I7XJWPJ.png) is how I see it on computer. I personally would also indent the lines inside of a `send_log()` function calls. But depends on a preference I guess. If you want me to suggest an edit with that, let me know. I would also maybe use less spaces for the indents, so it doesn't take up so much horizontal space.

Comment: Thank you for the reply again @MrMythical but...  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Comment: Also @SkulaurunMrusal ^

Comment: The error is because an instance `oldM` or `newM` of [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) doesn't have a property `.voice`. Just omit the `.voice` and write directly `.channel`.

Comment: not sure what you mean? Could you provide me a snippet of what you mean?

Comment: Rewrite `oldM.voice.channel` -> `oldM.channel`. The same goes for `newM`.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Just having issues cause the... `${newMember.user}` is coming back undefined? Could you assist with this aswell?

Comment: Use `${newMember.member.user}`. :)

Comment: Thank you. MrMythical and Skularun, works now!

Comment: That's great! By the way, @MrMythical you should probably update your answer with the info from comments.

Comment: Yes my bad, I was thinking that those were instances of `GuildMember`

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for letting me know about this.